# How to bind socket to a non local interface?

Tags: linux, sockets, esxi

I use the NAT address instead of the local interface address to bind socket call. I get this error -  Bind error (99): Cannot assign requested address. Is there any configuration settings that can be used to pass the IP of NAT instead of the IP of system for binding. I am running the program on esxi.

```
struct addrinfo hints;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
hints.ai_flags |= AI_PASSIVE; 

getaddrinfo(NATIP.c_str(), "0", &hint, &myAddr);
bind(sock, myAddr->ai_addr, myAddr->ai_addrlen);
```

Please let me know if this is possible or not?

Comment: You want to bind to an address that is not on your local machine?

Comment: Yes I want to bind to address not in my local machine. My NAT IP is from another system. Receiver will reject if its not coming from registered NAT IP.

Comment: You don't do that in the application software, that's done automatically by the NAT router.